# How do I communicate with a websocket within a Django API GET request?

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get a response from a websocket server (implemented with `websockets` and `asyncio`) from within a Django REST API method. Something of the following structure:

**Django App**

```
(This does not work, but illustrates the idea)

class AnAPI(views.APIView):

    async def get(self, request):
        try:
            timeout = 5
            try:
                ws_conn = await asyncio.wait_for(websockets.connect(WS_STRING), timeout)
            except ConnectionTimeoutError as e:
                 <.....>

            await ws_conn.send(...)
            response = await ws_conn.recv()
            ws_conn.close()
            return Response(...)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return Response(...)
```

**WS Server**

```
ws_server = websockets.serve(...)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(ws_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Apparently, this makes the Django GET method return a `<class 'coroutine'>`

```
AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'coroutine'>`
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

---

EDIT: Thanks to all of those who have answered! I was looking for a light weight solution as this is probably the only place where the Django app needed to interact with the WS server. I ended up adopting @Joran's solution, but packed everything into a helper function, something like this:

```
class AnAPI(views.APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        result = loop.run_until_complete(my_async_helper_function())
        return Response(...)


async def my_async_helper_function():

    try:
            timeout = 5
            try:
                ws_conn = await asyncio.wait_for(websockets.connect(WS_STRING), timeout)
            except ConnectionTimeoutError as e:
                 <.....>

            await ws_conn.send(...)
            response = await ws_conn.recv()
            await ws_conn.close()
            return ...
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            await ws_conn.close()
            return ...
```

Comment: I dont think you can return an async endpoint can you? ... just get rid of the async and i think it will work... but its more common with websockets that a js client connects to the socket, thather than an endpoint ... you basically loose pretty much all the benefits and suffer all of the bad parts about websockets by repeatedly connecting to them like a normal api call

Comment: @JoranBeasley I tried that earlier but I think if I want to use `await` in the function it's telling me I have to use `async` in front?

Comment: no i think you can use asyncio to call the function without await ... you might need some more controls to detect when you have the connection established

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yeah, it's a weird situation where the WS server is mostly interacting with a js client, but for this particular endpoint it would be nice if I were able to gather some info that's only available on that WS server..

Comment: `loop = asyncio.new_event_loop();
 asyncio.set_event_loop(loop);
 result = loop.run_until_complete(some_async_fn("django"))`  (or use something simpler (Im pretty sure there is a pure python websocket-client package out there that is dead simple to use))

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thanks for the pointer - I'll try a few things out and report back (probably in a day or two)

Comment: `pip install channels` and use [this](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as a reference

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed I don't think that the websocket is necesarilly his websocket... adn afaik channels does not include a websocket-client implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use async with django responses (I think...)

instead you could try

```
import asyncio

class AnAPI(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        try:
        timeout = 5
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop) 
        try:                
            ws_conn = loop.run_until_complete(websockets.connect(WS_STRING), timeout)               
        except ConnectionTimeoutError as e:
             <.....>

        loop.run_until_complete(ws_conn.send(...))
        response = loop.run_until_complete(ws_conn.recv())
        ws_conn.close()
        return Response(...)
```

alternatively I believe https://pypi.org/project/websocket_client/ offers a non async interface which is very easy to use

Comment: Thanks buddy! Updated my question (with the adopted solution)

Comment: that works reasonably well ... honestly i would recommend that other package for this particular use case... but yeah having a helper function probably doesnt hurt